# How to open file in vscode by command (without using Finder)?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Mac. I often want to peek a file. If it is in the current workspace, I can do it by `⌘P`, but it doesn't work for external files. For now, I use `⌘O` and select a file through Finder, but it is not comfortable. I want to do it using some command (like `Ctrl-X Ctrl-F` in emacs). Is there such command or extension?